# Want to sort a file based on another file in unix shell

Tags: shell, unix

I have 2 files refer.txt and parse.txt

refer.txt contains the following

```
julie,remo,rob,whitney,james
```

parse.txt contains

```
remo/hello/1.0,remo/hello2/2.0,remo/hello3/3.0,whitney/hello/1.0,julie/hello/2.0,julie/hello/3.0,rob/hello/4.0,james/hello/6.0
```

Now my output.txt should list the files in parse.txt based on the order specified in refer.txt

ex of output.txt should be:

```
julie/hello/2.0,julie/hello/3.0,remo/hello/1.0,remo/hello2/2.0,remo/hello3/3.0,rob/hello/4.0,whitney/hello/1.0,james/hello/6.0
```

i have tried the following code:

```
sort -nru refer.txt parse.txt
```

but no luck.

please assist me.TIA

Comment: So the fields are comma separated and internally slash separated and you need to sort them by first field and then third field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using gnu-awk:

```
awk -F/ -v RS=',|\n' 'FNR==NR{a[$1] = (a[$1])? a[$1] "," $0 : $0 ; next}
              {s = (s)? s "," a[$1] : a[$1]} END{print s}' parse.txt refer.txt
```

**Output:**

`julie/hello/2.0,julie/hello/3.0,remo/hello/1.0,remo/hello2/2.0,remo/hello3/3.0,rob/hello/4.0,whitney/hello/1.0,james/hello/6.0`

#### Explanation:

```
-F/                          # Use field separator as /
-v RS=',|\n'                 # Use record separator as comma or newline
NR == FNR {                  # While processing parse.txt
a[$1]=(a[$1])?a[$1] ","$0:$0 # create an array with 1st field as key and value as all the 
                             # records with keys julie, remo, rob etc.
}
{                            # while processing the second file refer.txt
  s = (s)?s "," a[$1]:a[$1]  # aggregate all values by reading key from 2nd file
}
END {print s }               # print all the values
```

Comment: Added some explanation in answer.

Comment: This is almost certainly going to be the best-performing answer on large inputs, and has my upvote for that reason. I'm inclined to keep my own answer around because, frankly, I think the builtins-only native-bash approach is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

In pure native bash (4.x):

```
# read each file into an array
IFS=, read -r -a values <parse.txt
IFS=, read -r -a ordering <refer.txt

# create a map from content before "/" to comma-separated full values in preserved order
declare -A kv=( )
for value in "${values[@]}"; do
  key=${value%%/*}
  if [[ ${kv[$key]} ]]; then
    kv[$key]+=",$value" # already exists, comma-separate
  else
    kv[$key]="$value"
  fi
done

# go through refer list, putting full value into "out" array for each entry
out=( )
for value in "${ordering[@]}"; do
  out+=( "${kv[$value]}" )
done

# print "out" array in comma-separated form
IFS=,
printf '%s\n' "${out[*]}" >output.txt
```

If you're getting more output fields than you have input fields, you're probably trying to run this with bash 3.x. Since associative array support is mandatory for correct operation, this won't work.

Comment: can we do using cut and grep?

Comment: Any approach using cut and grep would be much, much less efficient than the code here. (It would need to use grep once per line, invoking substantial invocation overhead -- and rereading the input file once per line of output!). I'm not interested in teaching people how to do things wrong, so I decline to participate in providing any such solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Command**

```
while read line; do
  grep -w "^$line" <(tr , "\n" < parse.txt)
done < <(tr , "\n" < refer.txt) | paste -s -d , -
```

**Key points**

- For both files, newlines are translated to commas using the `tr` command (without actually changing the files themselves). This is useful because `while read` and `grep` work under the assumption that your records are separated by newlines instead of commas.
- `while read` will read in every name from refer.txt, (i.e julie, remo, etc.) and then use `grep` to retrieve lines from parse.txt containing that name.
- The `^` in the regex ensures matching is only performed from the start of the string and not in the middle (thanks to @CharlesDuffy's comment below), and the `-w` option for `grep` allows whole-word matching only. For example, this ensures that "rob" only matches "rob/..." and not "robby/..." or "throb/...".
- The `paste` command at the end will comma-separate the results. Removing this command will print each result on its own line.

Comment: I'm split on whether to upvote this. On one hand, it's correct (so long as the names never evaluate to anything but themselves when treated as regular expressions, and so long as inputs don't contain literal backslashes or trailing whitespace that need to be preserved). On the other hand, it's completely awful from a performance perspective, and I'd argue that it's folks following this kind of bad practice that has lead some groups to argue that all shell scripts have awful performance by nature and Must Die.

Comment: Also, this doesn't filter by field, so "hello" would match every entry, even though "hello" isn't a name in parse.txt at all.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @CharlesDuffy. I updated the the `grep` command to match from the start of the string only. Also, I can't argue with your comments on performance. It's not exactly greased lightning, but the best thing it has going for it is brevity. If the OP is only doing some light work then its fine, but clearly there's a tradeoff between brevity and performance here.

Answer (score 0):

```
tr , "\n" refer.txt | cat -n >person_id.txt  # 'cut -n' not posix, use sed and paste

cat person_id.txt | while read person_id person_key
do 
    print "$person_id" > $person_key
done

tr , "\n" parse.txt | sed 's/(^[^\/]*)(\/.*)$/\1 \1\2/' >person_data.txt

cat person_data.txt | while read foreign_key person_data
do 
    person_id="$(<$foreign_key)"
    print "$person_id" " " "$person_data" >>merge.txt
done

sort merge.txt >output.txt
```

A text book data processing approach, a person id table, a person data table, merged on a common key field, which is the first name of the person:

[person_key] [person_id]
- person id table, a unique sortable 'id' for each person (line number in this instance, since that is the desired sort order), and key for each person (their first name)

[person_key] [person_data]
- person data table, the data for each person indexed by 'person_key'

[person_id] [person_data]
- a merge of the 'person_id' table and 'person_data' table on 'person_key', which can then be sorted on person_id, giving the output as requested

The trick is to implement an associative array using files, the file name being the key (in this instance 'person_key'), the content being the value.  [Essentially a random access file implemented using the filesystem.]

This actually adds a step to the otherwise simple but not very efficient task of grepping `parse.txt` with each value in `refer.txt` - which is more efficient I'm not sure.

NB: The above code is very unlikely to work out of the box.

NBB: On reflection, probably a better way of doing this would be to use the file system to create a random access file of `parse.txt` (essentially an index), and to then consider `refer.txt` as a batch file, submitting it as a job as such, printing out from the `parse.txt` random access file the data for each of the names read in from `refer.txt` in turn:

```
# 1) index data file on required field
cat person_data.txt | while read data
do
    key="$(print "$data" | sed 's/(^[^\/]*)/\1/')"  # alt. `cut -d'/' -f1` ??
    print "$data" >>./person_data/"$key"
done

# 2) run batch job
cat refer_data.txt | while read key
do
    print ./person_data/"$key"
done
```

However having said that, using `egrep` is probably just as rigorous a solution or at least for small datasets, I would most certainly use this approach given the specific question posed. (Or maybe not!  The above could well prove faster as well as being more robust.)